# Browser does not have rewritten URL with query string

Tags: nginx, rewrite

When I rewrite the URL by adding a query string, the URL in the browser does not have the query string.  Here's what I have:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /?page=test break;
}
```

Instead, I see the original URL in the browser when I visit the root directory.  I am able to rewrite to another path.

Comment: Why is this being -1?  You lose points by -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018761/django-web-server-removing-query-string-from-browser-url).  rewriting with a query string works.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is only a rewrite, which is (and should be) handled internally by the web server without the user being aware of it.

You can make this user-visible either temporarily or permanently by adding the `redirect` or `permanent` statements to your rewrite line ([nginx doc for rewrite](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)).

Be careful with the `permanent` variant ([HTTP Code 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)), the name is quite literal and the browser will store this so it's hard to change this afterwards - this should only ever be used to migrate to a new system.

Using `redirect` will force the browser to reload the site with the new URL, so this should be used with care as well, as it will add a significant delay to your page load times.

Comment: If I do ```rewrite ^/$ /test break;```, the browser URL shows ```/test```, so it is not handled internally.  Would using ```redirect``` be the same as doing a redirect in JavaScript?